# How to send audio properly over my local network to ExoPlayer client

Tags: c#, android, tcpclient, audio-streaming, exoplayer

My goal is streaming output sound of my computer to my android smartphone. What I have got? I can get output sound of my computer and can dump to a wav file. On the android client, I can play Internet radio streams or a wav file stored at remote servers by their URLs.

Before streaming output sound of my computer, I wanted to stream a wav file which is stored on my computer to my smartphone. My smartphone can connect to my computer but after sending a few packets, client closed the connection and I couldn't hear any sound.

I need help about how to stream a wav file over my local network, so ExoPlayer client can play it without a problem and eventually I want to stream my output sound of my computer live. I am open to tips, resources to read, code snippets, blogs about how can I do this, anything. Thanks in advance.

C# Server:

```
using System;
using System.Net;
using System.Net.Sockets;
using System.IO;

namespace TestApp
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            IPAddress ipAd = IPAddress.Parse("192.168.1.127");
            // use local m/c IP address, and 
            // use the same in the client

            /* Initializes the Listener */
            TcpListener myList=new TcpListener(ipAd,8001);

            /* Start Listeneting at the specified port */        
            myList.Start();
            
            Console.WriteLine("The server is running at port 8001...");    
            Console.WriteLine("The local End point is  :" + 
                            myList.LocalEndpoint );
            Console.WriteLine("Waiting for a connection.....");
            
            Socket socket=myList.AcceptSocket();
            Console.WriteLine("Connection accepted from " + socket.RemoteEndPoint);


            using (FileStream fsSource = new FileStream(
                @"C:\Users\tnc\Desktop\TestApp\dump.wav",
                FileMode.Open,
                FileAccess.Read
            )) {

                int bufferSize = 1024;
                byte[] buffer = new byte[bufferSize];
                long numBytesToRead = fsSource.Length;
                while (numBytesToRead > 0)
                {
                    int n = fsSource.Read(buffer, 0, bufferSize);
                    socket.Send(buffer, 0, n, 0);

                    // Break when the end of the file is reached.
                    if (n == 0)
                        break;

                    numBytesToRead -= bufferSize;
                }
            }

            socket.Close();
            myList.Stop();
        }
    }
}
```

Android Client: (I didn't want to put all the source file, this part is responsible for playing streamed audio)

```
 private void initializePlayer() {
    player = new SimpleExoPlayer.Builder(this).build();
    playerView.setPlayer(player);


    // Create a data source factory.
    DataSource.Factory dataSourceFactory = new DefaultHttpDataSourceFactory();
    // Create a progressive media source pointing to a stream uri.
    MediaSource mediaSource = new ProgressiveMediaSource.Factory(dataSourceFactory)
            .createMediaSource(MediaItem.fromUri("http://192.168.1.127:8001"));
    // Create a player instance.
    SimpleExoPlayer player = new SimpleExoPlayer.Builder(this).build();
    // Set the media source to be played.
    player.setMediaSource(mediaSource);

    player.setPlayWhenReady(true);

    // Prepare the player.
    player.prepare();
}
```

Comment: In android your url is http, so http protocol is assumed. However on PC you have raw tcp stream, no http.

Comment: @Evk, I was't aware of that, I tried removing "http://" but now I get "java.net.MalformedURLException: no protocol: 192.168.1.127:8001". ExoPlayer tries to make a http connection, thus audio should be streamed over http protocol.

Comment: Yes I don't suggest to change android part, I'd suggest to change server, to http one. For example, asp.net core. It runs as console application too, so heavy stuff like nginx\apache\IIS is not necessary.

Comment: Thank you, I will give it a try.